# Adding a line of text to php code

Tags: php, text, breadcrumb

My wordpress theme has a button to turn breadcrumbs on or off.

I want to leave the breadcrumb turned off and place a line of text where the breadcrumb would display on all pages except the home page.

You can see the breadcrumb here: http://greenesrelease.com/what-is-it/

I see in the `sub_page_header.php` where the breadcrumb is called

```
if(!is_front_page() &&  ( get_option('rttheme_breadcrumb_menus') || get_option(THEMESLUG.'_show_search') )){
    $info_bar = TRUE;
}else{$info_bar = FALSE;}
```

Answer (score 2):

[There is a difference between the home page and the front page.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) Since the code uses `is_front_page` I assume that is what you want, but check the Codex for the difference.

I don't know how your theme works, but it looks like the theme rolls several things into the "info bar". The code you posted just checks to see if there is any reason to display that bar.

```
if (
  !is_front_page()                          // does not show on the front page
  && (                                      // shows if either
    get_option('rttheme_breadcrumb_menus')  //     there is a breadcrumb option saved
    || get_option(THEMESLUG.'_show_search') //     or a search option
  )
){
  $info_bar = TRUE;
} else {
  $info_bar = FALSE;
}
```

You might be able to hack those conditionals to get something close to what you want but because the "info bar" does several different things I don't know that you can alter that to get exactly what you want. I think that the thing you need to alter is the code that generates the "info bar" itself.

I am refering to an "info bar" because there is an `$info_bar` variable. Right now, that variable name is all I have to go on. You will need to look for something that uses that `$info_bar` variable.  I expect if will look something like...

```
if($info_bar) {
  // some code probably 
  a_function_that_makes_the_infobar();
}
```

... but that is a guess. If you can find that function name then find the function itself...

```
a_function_that_makes_the_infobar() {
  // some code
}
```

... and *edit the code into your question*, I will revise the answer.

Comment: thanks for your response. there is no info bar on the front page. it contains breadcrumbs and a search bar, that is all. any suggestions where to look for the info bar? or what file?

Comment: @Janet : See the update